# How to pass selected row data to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview like this

[image]

I want to take the link and pass it to another controlview.

Here what i have done

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let linktopass = classes[indexPath.row].valueForKey("link")
    print(linktopass)


    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let thirdVC: web = segue.destinationViewController as! web

        thirdVC.link = linktopass as! String
```

But it does not work.

Here is my print's output.

```
Optional( http://blablabla )
```

Comment: what are you getting in `thirdVC.link` ?

Comment: no what's you get if you print this statement?

Comment: it is a link but not the one clicked. if i clicked to id=238 my link output is with 237

Comment: i click the first row but it takes second row's link.

the same for all rows.

Comment: means you are getting next object instead of current ?

Comment: yeah and it does not pass the data to second control view.

Comment: so, whats the problem? are you getting next object or you are unable to pass that object to next viewcontroller?

Comment: i get the object but i can not pass it to next viewcontroller.

Comment: what´s about  var link = ""  in thirdVC instead of 
   
 
var link = String()

Comment: For clarification, those are two separate code snippets, right?  I mean, you don't actually have prepareForSegue nested inside of the row selection method, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think you forget to `performsegue` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

`prepareForSegue` is get called before you `performsegue`. if you are not performing segue then your `prepareForSegue` will not called.

so, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, add code like,

```
  performSegueWithIdentifier("goToNextVC", sender: self) //your segue identifier here
  //goToNextVC is segue identifier set from attribute inspector from storyboard
```

Make sure you have set segue identifier from `attribute inspector`.

You can set identifier like,

select segue - click attribute inspector - write identifier in it - press enter

Hope this will help :)